# Menu - onCreate Event

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vb.net

In ArcObjects, the Class 'BaseCommand' has 'OnCreate' method(to handle oncreate event). Similarly is there any equivalent method available for Menu ('BaseMenu' Class)?